# NgRx and localStorage in combination

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, ngrx, state-management

I'm kind of new to the concept of NGRX and state management as I came from back-end development and whenever i see and heard the term state management one thing comes in my mind is CQRS.

Well, some of the articles in the internet says that it is patterned from that.
My Question is.. in my angular App.

Can i do something like, fetch data from the back-end then save to local storage if not exists? so every get request will look on the local storage and every save,update delete goes directly to a REST API then update the local storage if successful result form back-end?

I've been looking around for some examples about this but i am very unfortunate on that.

Also, reason why local storage is because I'm thinking PWA as well

Answer (score 7):

NGRX allows you to create a middleware [Document](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers).

Developers can think of meta-reducers as hooks into the action->reducer pipeline. Meta-reducers allow developers to pre-process actions before normal reducers are invoked.

```
import merge from 'lodash.merge';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './reducers';
 
export function storageMetaReducer<S, A extends Action = Action>(reducer: ActionReducer<S, A>) {
      return function(state: S, action: A): S {
        const nextState = reducer(state, action);
        const savedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__storage__')) || {};
        merge(nextState, savedState);
        localStorage.setItem('__storage__', nextState)
        return nextState;
      };
    }
    
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [storageMetaReducer];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
  ],
})
```

#### Main difference between localStorage vs sessionStorage

localStorage is persistent between tabs and sessionStorage is per tab.

Comment: Thanks for providing me that.. so I have to manualy write something that will check or insert into the cache from store

Comment: Yes, ngrx does not provide a solution that persist the data in the localStorage or sessionStroage. I think it is simple small function that can help you achieve what you need.

Comment: just another question sir.. what would be the strategy being used to sync data from the localstorage and the backend database?

Comment: similar to metaReducer for localStorage sync, you can create another metaReducer and add it to the list
`export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [storageMetaReducer, dataSyncReducer ];`
dataSyncReducer will make an ajax call post state to backend.

Comment: I see.. i really appreciate this.. but my use case really needs indexdb instead of localStorage due to storage capacity.. but not sure if i could use my created index db service class in a function based like this meta reducer