# How to cache data from API call then reload it using ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an angular 15 web application with ngrx state, with multiple components let`s say for an example feeds component; where it shows feeds fetched by an API call.

Is there a way to cache and preload these recently loaded data from local storage/indexdb?

or in general is there any other option that i can use to cache the data and to load it later whenever I reload the component, then do the sync call.

Putting in mind I have all loaded data saved in ngrx, and the data size is big so it will not fit into local storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NgRx and localStorage in combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543201/ngrx-and-localstorage-in-combination)

Comment: i have modified my question. so far my data size is big so using local storage is not an option unfortunately

Comment: You can probably take a similar approach using the browser's indexedDB. More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria

Comment: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/making-your-application-feel-faster-by-prefetching-data-with-ngrx